# Issue while assiging contentType:application/octet-stream to xml variable in soa

Tags: java, soa, bpel, oracle-soa

I am trying to assign a response from restful service to SOAP service. The response of restful service is in `application/octet-stream` which i am not able to assign to any variable. Currently I am using pojo to get the response which i am using in SOA BPEL using java callout.

`setVariableData("Token",response)` the type of Token is:

```
<xsd:element name="Token" type="xsd:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"/>
```

The element is defined in xsd.

but at runtime the error comes :

```
 <Error> <oracle.soa.bpel.engine.dispatch> <BEA-000000> <failed to handle message
com.oracle.bpel.client.BPELFault: faultName: {{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/}mismatchedAssignmentFailure}
messageType: {{http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension}RuntimeFaultMessage}
parts: {{
summary=<summary>Mismatch Assign.
cannot set a nonelement value to an element-based variable.
An attempt to assign a nonelement value to an element-based variable failed.
Verify the BPEL source for invalid assign activities.
</summary>}
```

Comment: I am working on oracle BPEL

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning to a variable based on an element. Try assigning to a variable of type xsd:base64Binary:

```
<variable name="VariableName" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
```

..and..

```
setVariableData("VariableName",response)
```